# read txt file nodejs without fs (from url)

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I'd like to read a file from some URL e.g

http://opensource.apple.com//source/vim/vim-6/vim/runtime/doc/filetype.txt

using a nodejs module:

```
exports.testR = function(word){

    loadFile("URL_HERE", function (responseText) {
       console.log(responseText);
    });
}
```

A pseudo code could be like:

```
var loadFile = function (filePath, done) {
    var fr = new FileReader()
    fr.onload = function () { return done(this.result); }
    fr.readAsText(filePath);
}
```

but FileReader will not work.

I can't use any `require` here. so `http` or `fs` won't work.

Is it possible to be done? Or I'm just wasting my time?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't import any modules at all?

Comment: JavaScript itself doesn't have any APIs to read files. That comes either from the browser (HTML5) or Node. If you don't have access to these APIs, then there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Can you elaborate *why* you cannot call `require`? Are there any other limitations?

Comment: it's just mandatory not to use any `require`. there's no other limitation.

Comment: maybe Felix is right and I should just delete the question.

Comment: @HugoS.Mendes i'd question why you aren't allowed to `require` standard nodejs libraries. How would this file be ran?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot *spell out* require, you can use a variant thereof, something like `global['req' + 'uire']` or `global[new Buffer('cmVxdWlyZQ==', 'base64').toString('ascii')]` to get to `require` and from then on load the modules you want.

If you cannot *call* `require`, `require.cache` is a list of loaded modules, and `http` or similar may occur therein.

`process.binding` (and its internal cousing `process._linkedBinding`) allows you to access native node.js modules; for instance `process.binding('tcp_wrap')` will get you the basic building blocks for making HTTP requests.

Alternatively, use `process.dlopen` to load a operating-system level library, such as libcurl, and use that to make the request.

Comment: I love you! I used `process.dlopen`. thank you very much.